# Laravel sort query result

Tags: php, laravel, sorting

I need to sort query after i use get since i append data to some objects of the query like this

```
  $the_result = myTable::where(..)->paginate();
  foreach( $the_result as $result)
  {
       if( some code )
       { 
           // append the pending_postion  to $result
           $result->pending_postion = $a_number; //number ex = 5 
       }
  }
```

so how to sort the $the_result by pending_postion ?

i tryed

```
$the_result ->sortBy('pending_postion');
collect($the_result )->sortBy('pending_postion');
return $the_result ;
```

the output

```
{
"current_page": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 226,
        "property_id": 40, 
        "is_pending": false
    },
    {
        "id": 227,
        "property_id": 40, 
        "is_pending": true,
        "pending_postion": 6
    },
    {
        "id": 228,
        "property_id": 40, 
        "is_pending": true,
        "pending_postion": 4
    },
     {
        "id": 229,
        "property_id": 40, 
        "is_pending": false
    },
```

]
}

Comment: Please show full unfolded output for `dd($result);` after you're appending the data.

Comment: You didn't show the full result. Also, do you have `pending_postion` in the `my_table` DB table?

Comment: no i append pending_postion to some objects only , i need to put those objects at the beginning of the array and put them with sort

Comment: It's impossible to help you if you don't show full results. `sortBy` works with what you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, you are getting `Collection` after using `get` method. So you can use 
[sort method for collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby)

```
foreach( $the_result as $result)
{
   if( some code )
   { 
       // append the pending_postion  to $result
       $result->pending_postion = $a_number; //number ex = 5 
   }
}
$the_result->sortBy('pending_postion');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a [sort](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sort) method like `sortBy()`

```
$the_result = myTable::where(..)->get()->sortBy('pending_postion');
```